# Oracle client and networking components were not found

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I created SSIS will do task like get data from oracle to sql server.i run ssis package run in my local system.it is working fine but i deployed ssis package in remote system and trying access from sql procedure. I'm getting error like below.

> Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version on 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Please let know if any solution there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest solution: The Oracle client is not installed on the remote server where the SSIS package is being executed.

Slightly less simple solution: The Oracle client is installed on the remote server, but in the wrong bit-count for the SSIS installation. For example, if the 64-bit Oracle client is installed but SSIS is being executed with the 32-bit `dtexec` executable, SSIS will not be able to find the Oracle client.
The solution in this case would be to install the 32-bit Oracle client side-by-side with the 64-bit client.

Comment: Yes I was getting this error because I was using the 64 bit Oracle client because my PC is 64 bit Windows, but I had to use the 32 bit Oracle client because Visual Studio is 32 bit.

Answer (score 10):

Technology used: Windows 7, UFT 32 bit, Data Source ODBC pointing out to 32 bit `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`, Oracle client with both versions installed 32 bit and 64 bit.

What worked for me:

1.Start -> search for `Edit the system environment variables`
2.System Variables -> `Edit Path`
3.Place the path for `Oracle client 32 bit` in front of the path for `Oracle Client 64 bit`.

Ex:

```
C:\APP\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_32\bin;C:\APP\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_64\bin
```

Comment: Or in my case, placing the Oracle 12 client in front of the Oracle 11 client. (our databases were recently upgraded to 12c)

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to My Computer Properties 
2.Then click on Advance setting. 
3.Go to Environment variable 
4.Set the path to

```
 F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\perl\5.8.3\lib\MSWin32-x86;F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\perl\5.8.3\lib;F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\perl\5.8.3\lib\MSWin32-x86;F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\perl\site\5.8.3;F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\perl\site\5.8.3\lib;F:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\sysman\admin\scripts;
```

change your drive and folder depending on your requirement...

Comment: hmmm... why -1? this is what happened in my case and the issue was resolved by adding appropriate folder to %path%

Answer (score 0):

After you install Oracle Client components on the remote server, restart SQL Server Agent from the PC Management Console or directly from Sql Server Management Studio.  This will allow the service to load correctly the path to the Oracle components. Otherwise your package will work on design time but fail on run time.

Comment: You should specify how this Oracle issue relates to MSSQL and the SQL Server Agent...

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because a file named **ociw32.dll** had been placed in **c:\windows\system32**. This is however only allowed to exist in **c:\oracle\11.2.0.3\bin**.

Deleting the file from system32, which had been placed there by an installation of Crystal Reports, fixed this issue