# OLEDB connection problem in visual studio 2017

Tags: oledbconnection

I am able to make ODP connection in visual studio, but when i make OLEDB connection it gives me error "oracel client and networking components were not found, please help me out".

Comment: Perhaps you need to install oracle's instant client? Did you check the docs of whatever package you're using to connect?

Comment: Thankx, now I am getting a different error after installation of  insta client "error while trying to retrieve the text for error ORA-01019", please help

Comment: Sorry, I think that error is due to having two Oracle clients installed. You must have already had an Oracle client installed, so I was wrong to suggest you needed to install Oracle's instant client. I think you should uninstall the Oracle instant client that I told you to install. My fault. After that, I would encourage you to check out this thread because I think it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002560/oracle-client-and-networking-components-were-not-found

Comment: Installing administrative client after the insta client solved the problem, thanks for the hint