# Oracle client and networking components were not found. Source Oracle Database SO AIX

Tags: oracle, ssis, aix, odac, oracleclient

I am using SSIS on windows, and I need to connect oracle database from aix system operative. I install the ODAC on my server but I have that error when I try to connect them.

Note* I also have install the oracle client and I can connect this database from Sql Developer

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle client and networking components were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002560/oracle-client-and-networking-components-were-not-found)

Comment: No, because i have installed the oracle client 64bits on the source server, is not 32bit version. Also I can connect from oracle IDE, the problem is with SSIS

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: Why are you using a version of ODAC from the 1990s? You need to upgrade ODAC, then you can use unmanaged ODP.NET or OraOLEDB. The client version to upgrade to depends on the SSIS version and the Oracle DB version being used. (You can use managed ODP.NET if you don't need BulkCopy functionality which is coming in a future release)

Comment: Make sure you are really  using ODAC and not Microsoft's deprecated old Microsoft OracleClient.